# NEAR "ExecutionError":"Exceeded the prepaid gas."

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm going through the tutorial in https://near.academy/near101/chapter-6

One of the steps is to run this command (but with my account):

```
near call museum.testnet add_meme \
'{"meme" : "bob", "title" : "god", "data" : "https://9gag.com/gag/ad8K0vj", "category" : 4}' \
--accountId YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME.testnet --amount 3
```

I keep getting errors like:

```
Log [museum.testnet]: attempting to create meme
    Failure [museum.testnet]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Exceeded the prepaid gas."}}

Transaction 9F9VUps6nN4myC8wzBUb1W1GTR4xV5WE had 30000000000000 of attached gas but used 2428115526258 of gas
```

It's a confusing error message because 30,000,000,000,000 > 2,428,178,132,410.

I have also tried running the command with `--amount 4` instead, but I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Benji at https://discord.com/channels/490367152054992913/542945453533036544/912840246524260355 suggested that instead of using `--amount 3` I use `--amount 3 --gas=75000000000000`, which worked.

Comment: In this case amount refers to the attached NEAR, and gas refers to the attached Gas to execute the tx. The ethereum equivalents would be value (for attached ETH), and gasLimit (for maximum number of gas to use on the tx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then you should use backslash , before every ".

near call museum.testnet add_meme '{"meme" : "Bob", "title" : "Jokes", "data" : "https://9gag.com/gag/aAGQ97L", "category" : 4}' --accountId NAME.testnet --amount 3 --gas=75000000000000